# How to call 2 api with same function in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have save function, so if the data is empty then post method must be called,if there is data already then put method must be implemented.
Can anyone help me to solve that.

Ts:

```
    saveEmergencyContact(itemrow) {
    console.log(itemrow,"itemrow");
    if(itemrow.Id!=null) {
      this._userService.editEmergencyContact(itemrow.Id).subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res,"edit");
        this.showSuccess("Emergency Contact updated succesfully");
        this.getEmergencyContact();
      })
    } else {
    this._userService.saveEmergencyContact(itemrow).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res,"add");
      this.showSuccess("Emergency Contact saved succesfully");
      this.getEmergencyContact();
    })
  }
}
```

If there is no Id, then it must work as above function, and if incase it has Id it must work as put function. Please help me out.

Here if i edit on the already data having section, it generates new section and i see 2 sections extra below that.
once after refresh, there will be one extra field.

Update:

```
 create() {
    return this._fb.group({
      ContactName: '',
      Phone: '',
      Relation: '',
    });
  }
```

Comment: so there are 5 elements in array, so id is there in that array, u can use id to add condition?

Comment: also, how are u pushing new data?

Comment: Ya i will update the code

Comment: what is  `this.uID` in that

Comment: that is the user id i got from particular user

Comment: ok, so you can use that id right?

Comment: no, that id is not what i wanted

Comment: ok, so you can add a temporary `id:0` in create

Comment: ya added, then do i need to declare anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's what you're looking for:

```
 saveEmergencyContact(itemrow) {
    if(itemrow.id!=null)
    {
      this._userService.editEmergencyContact(itemrow).subscribe(...)
    }
    else
    {
      this._userService.addEmergencyContact(itemrow).subscribe(...)
    }
      }
```

Comment: this was just an idea, you need to implement editEmergencyContact and addEmergencyContact in your userService

+of course amend ... for a proper logic

Comment: ya in service i have passed this with an id